# finding the previouspage control on current page

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [previouspage.findcontrol getting variable from previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984883/previouspage-findcontrol-getting-variable-from-previous-page)

Hi am new to asp am using this code to get the value of textbox from the previous page 
here is my code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            name1 = (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("name");
            Response.Write(name1.Text);
        }
```

but this code returns the value of `textbox name1=""`

anyone can help me.....regarding this problem

Comment: Are you using `Server.Transfer` from another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try sessions
 put previous pages textbox value to session like..

```
 urtextbox.Text=Session["value"].ToString();
```

you declare this session in previous page then call it in current page
then this session you can use in your entire application for getting that textbox value..

Comment: Yes session is the another way to transfer value.

Comment: then you can simply use that..

Answer (score 2):

You should post first page to second page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br /><br />                                     
<asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/SecondPage.aspx" Text="Go To Second Page" /></div></form>
```

secondPage.aspx.cs

```
if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
{    
    // Now we call the FindControl method to get the control
    TextBox name1 = (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("name");
    Label1.Text = name1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Server.Transfer, you will have to send the value of the control to the next page when leaving the previous page. You could possibly store it in a querystring?

The state of the previous page will clear when you leave it so you will have to store the values you want to keep somewhere, e.g querystring, session..etc

Comment: He is right steen, the PreviousPage Property can be used only while doing Server.Transfer or CrossPagePosting. See Msdn:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx